# Compile check if compiling as static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, static-libraries

How can i check at compilation if the project is being compiles as a lib ? (static library)

Is there some kind of static assert or some other flag i can check?

I can't add a preprocessor variable myself, because it's a utility that will be used in other projects across the company. So I'm wondering if there's some preprocessor flag that is is being sent by default or something.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Depends on the tools and compiler. Do you want an answer for Visual C++ or for g++ ?  How are you compiling your project now?

Comment: In comparison to what? To a dynamic lib or to an executable? The latter one won't work (reliably, cross-platform), as this is decided at link time. The former might be possible though. You might still be better of by just adding a preprocessor variable yourself.

Comment: Add a `-DSTATIC_LIBRARY` to the command line and test with `#ifdef`?

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2010. I can't add a preprocessor variable myself, because it's a utility that will be used in other projects across the company.

Comment: if static libraray also means linking statically against the crt (not always the case, but might be for you), then you can check on `_DLL`: it won't be defined for the static crt

Comment: Yea i thought about checking for _DLL , but then i'm not sure it's defined to always be present if compiling as a dynamic link. And further more, I'll have to do other checks to see if it's compiling as an .exe for example.

Comment: Your code is terrible if it depends on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such thing in predefined macro list - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.100%29.aspx .

But by default MSVC adds `_LIB` to preprocessor definition list, if it's a "static library" project.
(also it adds `_USRDLL` for DLLs)

**Edit:** In Visual Studio 2017 the definition for DLLs is `_WINDLL` (from the "Windows Dynamic Link Library" property sheet applied by the IDE). The `_LIB` definition is no longer available.

An alternative solution is to add a property sheet to the project (checked into your version control repository) with the following preprocessor definition: `_$(OutputType);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)`.

`$(OutputType)` will resolve as "library" for DLLs and "staticlibrary" for static libraries, resulting in `_library` and `_staticlibrary` definitions respectively (or `_exe` for applications).

`%(PreprocessorDefinitions)` will stack definitions from previous property sheets. Make sure it is included in the project properties as well!

To add a property sheet, navigate to **View | Other Windows | Property Manager** in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, I don't exactly see what's wrong with adding your own preprocessor define. Reasoning behind that is that you *have to supply project files anyway*, so the option would be properly distributed with project file.

Or, you could mean "how to check if **a file** is being compiled as a library" - there's no way (other than compiler define).

Comment: Because the project is not mine. I'm creating a header file with code that isn't supposed to work with static libraries.

Comment: The most sensible would be to just go to the project owner and ask if you or he could put the appropriate option in it, because it's really the easiest way.

Comment: The company is bigger than that.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer wouldn't that make your problem _different_ and more suited to, maybe, [P.SE]?

Comment: No, i mean i need a programming solution, not a "go and tell everybody" solution. If it was my solution or project I'd use it correctly. But when working on infrastructure you need to do it programaticaly and look to the future. Infrastructure can't be dependendant on shaky personal knowledge, it's supposed to work and keep working without any external involvement like adding extra variables.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I'd say writing code that's dependent on type of compilation target (executable or library) is **even more** fragile and shaky. You could at least split it into two files and compile one or another.

Comment: That's really narrow minded. The problem with static libraries is static variables. If you have 2 dll's compile with the same static library you'll have 2 instances of the static variable. I want to avoid that. It's not a matter of separating files. It's a matter of memory management with static variables. And it's far from bad design (look at the singleton pattern for example), there are cases where you only want one instance throughout the program.

Comment: Singleton pattern actually lies very near to "bad design" in my pattern scale.

Comment: @Yochai "I'm in favor of dropping Singleton. Its use is almost always a design smell." — [says Erich Gamma](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1404056), one of [the famous GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) who made it so popular. If you want a more elaborate discussion, SO user [jalf has it](http://jalf.dk/singleton) on his blog.

Answer (score -1):

What a particular assembly builds as is explicitly set in the vcxproj file, it's known and set before compile time. What may be tricky is that in your solution file's settings that show up in the configuration manager your solution configuration and platform may have settled upon some wonky project configuration and platform that's discrepant for your solution build.

In the vcxproj xml the build output type will show up as the value for the `<ConfigurationType>` element.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Analogously in the project Property Pages in the `Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type` is where you specify what your assembly builds as. You may even deviate with the target extension if that makes sense, for instance when building some BoostPython stuff I change dll to pyd.

[image: Project Property highlighting Configuration Type setting]

To highlight the sort of wonky mixup I'm talking about, which may have come by mistake or a flawed merge or something, you can check what your itemized build settings are for each project under the solution configuration. I give an example below where the solution platform is ReleaseOffline but various projects in the solution are dialed in to Release, DebugStatic, etc. Many of the projects are turned off in the screenshot but you can imagine a mixup of dependencies getting things into a bad state mixing build types. Some mixups may be intentional so make sure you know what you're doing/looking for since Visual Studio lends this sort of flexibility in these configurations. Remember too that the settings you see are specific to the configuration/platform pair that is selected. Change either of those and you're likely to see changes in the values for all that was discussed above.

[image: Sample project configuration mixup in configuration manager]