# What is it called when implementations (of a group of singletons) self-register in some registry directly from their compilation unit in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Suppose we have such scheme:

qqqapi.h:

```
int register_qqq(Qqq* klass);
```

qqqalpha.cpp:

```
QqqAlpha::QqqAlpha(...) : Qqq(...) { }

QqqAlpha instance;
int dummy = register_qqq(&instance);
```

qqqbeta.cpp:

```
QqqBeta::QqqBeta(...) : Qqq(...) { }

QqqBeta instance;
int dummy = register_qqq(&instance);
```

This way you can create new qqq types just by copying the source and header file, changing the appropriate identifiers. No need to manually add any things to any list.

How this pattern is called? Are there any recommendations about implementing such things properly?

Comment: Not every splice of code has a name. Recommendations: place the dummy variable into an unnamed namespace, mark it as const (and probably better to make a special class to do this, instead of creating a function that returns a meaningless integer), and give it a unique named hidden behind a macro so people cannot accidentally touch it. All this will help ensure the linker can remove it from the final executable, and make it easier to use. Final thing should look like `REGISTER_QQQ(instance);`. But this is usually done to register *types* paired with strings (i.e., construction functions)...

Comment: ...not instances. Instances should register themselves if that's part of their construction contract. Regardless, this isn't a good question for SO since there's no authoritative guideline to how this should be done.

Comment: A hilariously bad design.

Comment: @DeadMG, What do you suggest instead? My the only other idea currently is to scan though source code for implementations and code-generate the registry file before compilation. But this requires more build dependencies and customisations of build file...

Comment: @Vi.: I have no idea what would be a good design (and no patience to look at your question), but I have just today commented [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052944/compile-check-if-compiling-as-static-library/14053342#comment19422880_14053342) on another singleton question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A main problem with this scheme is that a C++ implementation deals with whole *translation units*.

Consider a static library that includes hundreds of translation units. As far as the compiler and linker knows, your program is only using one or two. Little do they know that by way of auto-registration in a registry object, your program is actually using five units!

So, the linker removes all translation units that the library provides, except the one or two that are *directly* used by your code, e.g. by calling functions or referring to variables.

Result: mysterious runtime failure, where the singleton registry somehow doesn't contain what it should.

This is possibly a reason why the pattern/idiom/whatchammacallit is little used. It works fine for object code files, because then you're explicitly telling the linker what to include. It works less fine for static libraries.

---

A best practice is to ensure, best via code but possibly via documentation, that something from the translation unit is called or referred to, e.g. by `main`.

This ensures that there's a *visible* dependency, so that the translation unit is not removed.

---

I do not know any commonly used name for this. In the old days, with another language, there was something called a *module envelope*, which you can think of as execution of constructor and destructor of a static object responsible for initialization and cleanup of the module. But C++ does not support that, and as I recall, googling the term in recent years did not provide any relevant hits; it's like all information about that disappeared...

Comment: Are there any Qt-specific helpers for this maybe?

Comment: BTW should I call the thing "Singleton Registry"? Or it does not imply such self-registering?..

Comment: The name of a dog does not matter so much as long as the dog responds to it, and others know of which dog you're speaking.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Would a translation unit really allowed to be "optimized away" even in the presence of side effects visible outside that translation unit (as in this example)? -- Your suggestion about explicitly referring to the translation unit doesn't align with the OPs requirements.

Comment: @user946850: yes, when a translation is discarded from the set of included translation units, it is "really" discarded. and yes compilers do that. that's why i wrote that it happens. u now, because it does. regarding the "suggestion", it's quite misleading of you (who, to top it off, is anonymous on the internets, possibly a dog) to call it that. a logical requirement is not a suggestion. it is a logical requirement. you might as well talk about the suggestion that the Earth revolves around the Sun. this relationship is not a suggestion. it is a fact. do you understand this?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thank you so much for enlightening me.